# 3.x form array?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, jform, fields

Is there a way to have the same field in an array when posting the data? Since I need the tabs in my component to be generated dynamically depending on the querys output, I can't enter them specifically into that file.

models/forms/myform.xml

```
<fieldset name="myset"
    <field name="language" type="language" class="hidden" ...>
    <field name="sometext" type="text" ...>
/>
```

view/myview/tmpl/default.php

```
foreach ($langs as $lang)
{
    /* html */
    $this->form->setFieldAttribute('language', 'default', $lang['name']);
    echo $this->form->renderFieldSet('myset');
    /* html */
}
```

would result in say this:

| English | German | French |

with a language and text field on each tab. The problem here is that when posting it just posts the last state, that would be the contents of 'French'. So is there a way to fix this and make joomla send an array or any better solutions to this issue?

Furthermore, is there a way to say Joomla to put that data into a stdObject because anything in that fieldset is related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiple fields with same name**

`multiple="true"` means that your one field can have multiple values, not that you can have multiple fields with same name.

You have to create [custom form field](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) to get multiple textareas or selects with same name.

Since you only have to add `[]` to end of fields name, `extend` `JFormFieldTextarea` and `JFormFieldList`. Then you only have to copy-paste existing `getInput` functions and add `[]` after `$this->name`.

These classes are located at `libraries/joomla/form/fields`, files `list.php` and `textarea.php`.

**Grouping**

Only way you can group related data is to add `<fieldset></fieldset>` into `<fields></fields>`

Example from Joomla! core `com_content` article.xml:

```
<fields name="attribs" label="COM_CONTENT_ATTRIBS_FIELDSET_LABEL">
  <fieldset name="basic" label="COM_CONTENT_ATTRIBS_FIELDSET_LABEL">
    <field
      name="show_title"
      type="list"
      class="chzn-color"
      label="JGLOBAL_SHOW_TITLE_LABEL"
      description="JGLOBAL_SHOW_TITLE_DESC">
      <option value="">JGLOBAL_USE_GLOBAL</option>
      <option value="1">JSHOW</option>
      <option value="0">JHIDE</option>
    </field>
</fields>
```

Now, the output would be.

```
<select id="jform_attribs_show_title" name="jform[attribs][show_title]" class="chzn-color chzn-done" style="display: none;">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Use Global</option>
  <option value="1">Show</option>
  <option value="0">Hide</option>
</select>
```

All `fields` in this `fieldset` will be in `jform[attribs]`. `<fields>` attribute `name` would be `array` key.

In the end you will end up with something like this.

```
<fields name="grouped">
  <fieldset name="myset"
      <field name="language" type="mycustomlanguage" class="hidden" ...>
      <field name="sometext" type="mycustomtext" ...>
  />
</fields>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `multiple="true"` in field xml

`<field name="language" type="language" class="hidden" multiple="true" ...>`

Comment: Well, that works with language but not with text and textarea.

Comment: textarea can not have multiple values. But still you need it, you can put [] in name. like name="sometext[]" . But I am not sure that it will work or not.

Comment: the name resulting would be jform[sometext[]], must be jform[sometext][]

Comment: Then it won't work.